# How to avoid react from referencing to the same object and instead create a new copy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react class like this:

```
class TextDropDown extends Component {
    
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.DropDownElements = this.props.Values.map((element,ind) => ({
            value: element,
            isChecked: false,
            id: "DropdownElems:" + this.props.UniqueIdentifier + ind,

        }));

        this.ClearAllElements = this.DropDownElements.slice();
        this.SelectAllElements = this.ClearAllElements.slice().map(elem => {
            elem.isChecked = true
            return elem;
        });
        console.log("[DropDown Elements]: ");
        console.log(this.DropDownElements);
        console.log("[ClearAll Elements]: ");
        console.log(this.ClearAllElements);
        // console.log("[SelectAll Elements]: ");
        // console.log(this.SelectAllElements);
        //Double Data Storage => Can be inefficient when dealing with big data
    }
}
```

what I am observing is that even though I use slicing and `[...this.dropDownElements]` still all of the three variables `this.ClearAllElements`, `this.SelectAllElements` and `this.DropDownElements` end up having the same value in console.

On the other hand when I comment out the SelectAllElements operation, the values seem to be the same for DropDownElements and ClearAllElements. I just want to know when I am creating a new data by using `slice()` or ES6 copying syntax, then why am I still getting the same value for all three variables.

Comment: `SelectAllElements` and `ClearAllElements` aren't "operations", you're doing mutations right there and then, and you end up mutating the inner objects.

Comment: Also, you essentially "fork props into state" here, which is considered bad from; if you do this, changing props will not cause re-renders, which will confuse you down the line.

Comment: `slice()` and `[...this.dropDownElements]` won't clone the objects inside the `dropDownElements`

Comment: Then what will be the way to clone it?

Comment: use `.map()` method to iterate over the array and return a new object in each iteration

Comment: you mean `this.ClearAllElements = this.DropDownElements.map(elements => elements)`

Comment: `this.ClearAllElements = this.DropDownElements.map(elements => {...elements})` and also not if `elements` object contains nested objects, you need to clone them as well.